# Facebook API returns 'Unsupported post request' when adding users to Custom Audience

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

When I try to add users to a Custom Audience (using a POST to endpoint `/{custom_audience_id}/users`, with parameters `users` and `hash_type`), it gives me

{'error': {'message': 'Unsupported post request.', 'code': 100, 'type': 'GraphMethodException'}}

This message has popped up for other people on Stack Overflow when they try to do things for which they did not get the right Facebook permissions, but I do have ads_management permissions for the user (the user is actually my own account, so I have all the permissions). I have Ads API Access, and the message at the top of (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-api) says that even though Custom Audience API Access is different from Ads API Access, if you have Ads API Access then you also have Custom Audience API Access. And Ads API Access is not the issue (I can create Ad Campaigns, Ad Sets, Custom Audiences, etc.).

In conclusion, I have ads_management permission and Ads API Access, and can do a bunch of Ads stuff already, except when I try to add users to a Custom Audience, I get the above JSON-formatted error. Any guidance on why, or at least how to go about figuring out why?

(and the Facebook error code explanation for 100, "Invalid parameter", is largely no help, as are the vague error message and error type)

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to update the audience whose ID you're using? {edit: and that it hasn't been deleted?}

Comment: The User who's ID I'm using is me, and I created a Custom Audience (among many other things) on behalf of this ID, so I definitely have ads_management permission, right? And I print the Custom Audience ID right before trying to add users to it, so it's definitely not deleted.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the `users` JSON array supposed to look like? I have [{'email_hash': <string-which-is-sha256-hash-of-an-email-address>}]. The linked doc page doesn't have any real examples (it calls them examples but they leave the users list as [{'email_hash': 'HASH'}, ...] which is still using generic names instead of actual examples, so it's ambiguous what 'email_hash' and 'HASH' are supposed to be)

Comment: maybe take a look at this:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/examples/custom_audiences.php

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I found the mistake, and it was that I passed the Account ID instead of the Audience ID accidentally, so of course it's going to give me an issue with that endpoint :/ I'm dumb sometimes.