# Create Custom Audience On Facebook API, users parameter ambiguity?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/#create gives examples of adding users to a Custom Audience, but they leave in generic names => `[{'email_hash: 'HASH'} ...]` so they are not actually examples.

What (EXPLICITLY) do 'email_hash' and 'HASH' represent and could someone give an actual example (just a couple users long would be perfect)?

My current guess is that the string 'email_hash' is literally the string `'email_hash'`, and that 'HASH' is a hash of an email, like `hashlib.sha256("example@example.com").hexdigest()`, which would be a super long random-looking string like `'afiouh34r78efiu9h3fuio20h8ui45grt43'`. But this is currently not working for me (though the format of `users` is not necessarily problem, I would just like to definitively rule it out).

Comment: Have you read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/#hash ?

Comment: Ya, that page's "examples" were the same, no actual values provided. Hashing is not the difficulty. It's what values 'email_hash' and 'HASH' are supposed to represent. 'email_hash' and 'HASH' could both conceivably be the hashed version of an email (something like 'feho8ui34fhui4fh38oui'), and both could conceivably be the hash type used (like 'md5' or 'sha256'), or they could be something else I haven't thought of, but whatever I'm doing is not working.

Comment: So I would like an actual example, which would be nice for Facebook to have put in its docs :/

Comment: Replace HASH with the hash

Comment: Ok, that's what I assumed, so something else is my problem.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515115/facebook-api-returns-unsupported-post-request-when-adding-users-to-custom-audi

Comment: I really appreciate any help I can get, so thanks

Comment: please provide more information about errors, there is not enough information to answer your questions.

Comment: This question was not about errors, it was about the format of the `users` parameter. The question I linked to I gave the error response I got. I'm not really sure what else to give. (I agree it's very little to work with, but that's all FB gives me.) Perhaps there are strategies to get more clues or more verbose errors?

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. My problem was that I was not passing the ID I thought I was as the endpoint, and the format of `users` was not the issue. I appreciate the help very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl \
-F 'payload={"schema":"EMAIL_SHA256","data":["6cce3cf897cd3d2e28a293c00d3e6481241f7e3b3c3d48a1c2730810d416e522","cf55271c41b355553db350e1f218e09b585c1f30319041c5c4a8f209f4a8072b","fd9486ac1e02b9848619cd628ee36b9a0f010b237930f4d0c32d213ab1e6cf88","7afb43906db4882f94dd9d7bea495b4da095293a4f53d21ba67322ffa8e8b8c6","e270020a98195d74cf639e2de34d5c845f2f30e402523a02e05dfc9e8a2dd1f1","5a6b2d94b340d55537ab7e7d81ad201461db11db55573194a0ee059dd1ec645d","cfa159538bbf52cecebc72cd34a99000c0e75be133c2264c45e57c8ef99abc8c"]}' \
-F 'session={"session_id":524717974,"batch_seq":1,"estimated_num_total":10200,"last_batch_flag":true}' \
-F 'access_token=CAAXkgWuehJkBALLqJM' \
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/603517/users
```